# Unable to remove change inline CSS or remove the whole style attribute from my div after initially setting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:**

I have a dropdown menu and upon clicking its title, I change the colour of the title. What I intend to do is, when the menu is closed, either by clicking on the title or one of the links in the dropdown list, reset the text back to the colour it originally was.

I can set the title's colour, but no matter what I do, I can not set it back to black.

**What I've tried:**

From within an on click function for one of the links in the list, I:
- set the css
- set the attr to ''
- removed the style

None of these had any effect. I used chrome developer tools to check, and the css is never changed, and it's style is never removed.

I also put the click inside the menu title's on click function, and accessed the title using $(this). That never worked either.

I also tried adding a class to the HTML, applying the color for the title, the removing the class. Then in JS, I added it back and then tried to remove it. However, it never got removed. I know I'm referencing the title properly because I added some code to change the text of the title when a menu title is clicked. So it can't be a referencing problem.

I narrowed down as much as I could. In the end, I thought it could be a problem with my dev environment. So I replicated the functionality in JSFiddle and got the same result. This tells me I'm missing something.

**Here's my code:**

HTML

```
<div class="menu-title-container">
  <div class="menu-title">Title</div>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a class="menu-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="selected-link-container">
  <div class="selected-link">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-container a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
$(".menu-title-container").on('click', function() {

  $(this).find(".menu-container").slideToggle();
  $(this).find(".menu-title").css("color", "blue");

});


$(".menu-link").on('click', function() {

  $(this).parent().parent().find(".menu-title").text("I can definitely find you");
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".menu-title").css("color", "red");

  $(this).parent().parent().find("menu-title").attr("style", "");
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".menu-title").removeAttr("style");


});
```

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/3pwdrsyv/1/

Comment: The first click event is always called even on clicks on the child elements. Use console.log() to log your events being called and you will figure it out.

Comment: upon clicking on '.menu-link' you are actually also clicking on '.menu-title-container'. Bubbling up... first the link turns red, but then the container turns blue again. Turn off the color in container and you will see it turns red.

Comment: Yep, I tried this earlier and still couldn't figure it out. I know understand what's going on. Adding: event.stopPropagation(); makes things work, but breaks other functionality. I will try and figure it out.

Comment: Simply write a condition on .menu-title-container click that if ... >>> do/don't change the color or any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the clue left by the first 2 commenters, I was able to fix the issue.

**The lines that fixed the issue:**

```
  event.stopPropagation(); // The name of the function is self-explanatory
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".menu-container").slideToggle(); // Close meny
```

**Complete code with changes:**

```
 $(".menu-title-container").on('click', function() {

      $(this).find(".menu-container").slideToggle();
      $(this).find(".menu-title").css("color", "blue");

    });


        $(".menu-link").on('click', function() {

          event.stopPropagation();
          $(this).parent().parent().find(".menu-container").slideToggle();

          $(this).parent().parent().find(".menu-title").text("I can definitely find you");


          $(this).parent().parent().find(".menu-title").removeAttr("style");


        });
```

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/uxqh6vya/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this behaviour? https://jsfiddle.net/76cnL3gm/

```
$(".menu-title-container").on('click', function(event) {

  $(".menu-container").slideToggle();
  $(".menu-title").css("color", "blue");
  console.log('title-container');
});


$(".menu-link").on('click', function(event) {
  //event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  $(".menu-title").text("I can definitely find you");
  //$(".menu-title").css("color", "red");

  $(this).text("Clicked");

  //$("menu-title").attr("style", "");
  $(".menu-title").removeAttr("style");
  console.log('menu-link');

});
```